# Игнорирование методов при обходе таблицы

Tags: lua, методы

У меня есть таблица `clients`, которую я обхожу с помощью `pairs`. Также, я использую два метода: `add` и `del`. Как данные методы игнорировать, не вставляя проверку на то, функция ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метатаблицу:

```
clientops = {}; -- В эту таблицу пишите методы
clients = setmetatable({}, {__index = clientops}); -- Назначить таблицу методов
```

Теперь добавляйте методы для `clients` в `clientops` (при вызове через `:` первым параметров всё равно приходит `clients`).

Comment: небольшой пример использования совсем бы не помешал, как мне кажется.

Comment: @alex, на самом деле, это из моей практики, но пример попробую составить.